# NFS + SSH tunnel (Local Drive Mounted to VPS)

Tags: ssh, nfs

I'm trying to follow this guide https://fillumina.wordpress.com/2022/10/18/best-way-to-share-a-folder-between-linux-pcs-nfs-vs-smb-vs-sshfs/ where it concludes at **Installation of NFS + SSH tunnel**

## Note: The vps wants to connect to the computer to use the computers external drive

---

#### on the local computer

```
apt-get install nfs-kernel-server nfs-common portmap
```

```
nano /etc/exports
```

add:

```
/mnt/mn1 102.254.243.168(insecure,rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

save the restart

```
systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server.service
```

```
iptables -A INPUT -i enp4s0f0 -p tcp --dport 22 -s 102.254.275.167 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp4s0f0 -p tcp --dport 3049 -s 102.254.275.167 -j ACCEPT
ufw allow from 102.254.275.167 to any port nfs
```

#### on the vps

```
apt-get install nfs-common portmap
```

```
mkdir /mnt/mn1
```

```
ssh -fNv -L 3049:localhost:2049 root@164.238.71.109 -i nas
```

This part does not work

```
mount -v -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=3049 164.238.71.109:/mnt/mn1 /mnt/mn1
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Oct 28 18:19:00 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'proto=tcp,port=3049,vers=4.2,addr=164.238.71.109,clientaddr=102.254.275.167'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

tried this also

```
mount -v -t nfs4 -o verproto=tcp,port=3049 164.238.71.109:/mnt/mn1 /mnt/mn1
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Sat Oct 28 18:06:15 2023
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'verproto=tcp,port=3049,vers=4.2,addr=164.238.71.109,clientaddr=102.254.275.167'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'verproto=tcp,port=3049,vers=4.1,addr=164.238.71.109,clientaddr=102.254.275.167'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'verproto=tcp,port=3049,vers=4.0,addr=164.238.71.109,clientaddr=102.254.275.167'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'verproto=tcp,port=3049,addr=164.238.71.109'
mount.nfs4: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs4: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs4: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs4: portmap query failed: RPC: Unable to receive - Connection refused
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'verproto=tcp,port=3049,vers=4.0,addr=164.238.71.109,clientaddr=102.254.275.167'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'verproto=tcp,port=3049,addr=164.238.71.109'
mount.nfs4: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs4: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs4: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs4: portmap query failed: RPC: Unable to receive - Connection refused
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'verproto=tcp,port=3049,vers=4.0,addr=164.238.71.109,clientaddr=102.254.275.167'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'verproto=tcp,port=3049,addr=164.238.71.109'
mount.nfs4: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs4: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs4: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
```

#### Additional info

on the local machine

```
rpcinfo -p | grep nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs

nmap -Pn 102.254.275.167
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-10-28 16:58 WEST
Nmap scan report for hostname.com (102.254.275.167)
Host is up (0.16s latency).
Not shown: 969 filtered ports, 30 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  60788  status
    100024    1   tcp  34639  status
    100005    1   udp  42895  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  46313  mountd
    100005    2   udp  55483  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  38869  mountd
    100005    3   udp  47377  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  44549  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100021    1   udp  60048  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  60048  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  60048  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  45775  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  45775  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  45775  nlockmgr

systemctl status nfs-server.service
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
             └─order-with-mounts.conf
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2023-10-28 16:54:42 WEST; 31min ago
    Process: 6470 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 6471 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 6471 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 5ms

oct 28 16:54:42 benz systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
oct 28 16:54:42 benz systemd[1]: Finished NFS server and services.
```

on the vps

```
lsof -i :3049
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ssh     1578 root    4u  IPv4  37815      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:3049 (LISTEN)
ssh     1578 root    5u  IPv6  37816      0t0  TCP localhost:3049 (LISTEN)

rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  47567  status
    100024    1   tcp  33615  status
```

Answer (score 0):

SSH `-L` tunnels are established on 127.0.0.1/::1 (localhost) on the client machine, as your 'lsof' shows. But you're mounting directly using the server's IP address – doing so completely bypasses the tunnel and makes a direct connection. That fails because the server is still listening on port 2049 (not 3049).

If you want to go through the SSH tunnel, specify `localhost:/mnt/mn1` as the mount source. (Doing so makes the server's ufw configuration irrelevant, and in fact you should *close* the NFS port unless you're using Kerberos security.)

Note that on the server side, the connection via the tunnel will *also* appear as if it's coming from localhost, not from the client's original address, so you need to adjust /etc/exports for that.

"Invalid argument" most likely shows up because `verproto=` is not a valid option. It looks like `vers=4.2,proto=tcp` was meant instead. You can omit it entirely – NFSv4 only supports TCP anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but `mount -v -t nfs -o port=3049 localhost:/mnt/mn1 /mnt/mn1` how will that typed into the vps know where on earth my local computer is?

Comment: removed `ufw allow from 102.254.275.167 to any port nfs` ty

Comment: Is your VPS the machine that's serving the NFS share and the local computer connecting to it, or the other way around?

Comment: The vps wants to connect to the computer to use the computers external drive (yes the other way round!)

Comment: Are you running the `ssh -L` on the local computer or the VPS? It already sounds like you want `-R` instead, to forward connections from remote to local.

Comment: -L on the vps (to connect to the computer)

Comment: In that case, it knows because localhost:3049 is where your SSH client is listening, and you *already told* your SSH client to forward connections from the client's localhost:3049 to the SSH server's localhost:2049 (where NFS is).

Comment: wow now df -h shows the drive attached but `touch: cannot touch '/mnt/mn1/x': Read-only file system`

Comment: maybe chown nobody:nogroup /mnt/mn1 before mount